# finding datatypes for 802.11 frame

Tags: c++, networking, types, wifi

So i'm constructing a datatype in c++ for a 802.11 frame. Something like

```
typedef struct {
uint16_t frame_control;
uint16_t duration_id;
uint64_t address1;
uint64_t address2;
uint64_t address3;
uint64_t sequence_control;
uint16_t address4;
unsigned frame_body;
uint16_t fcs;
 } frame;
```

Now i'm looking for the 'best' datatypes for this. Is there a way to use smaller datatypes, for i.e. i don't truly need unint64_t for the addresses.
Also i dont know a good datatype for the frame_body, because it's just between 0 and 2312 bytes in size.

[image]

Comment: The addresses are `char[6]`.

Comment: Can i make all of them just `char[byte-size]` i.e. `char frame_control[2]` . I want to keep the datatype as small as possible.

Comment: Certainly you can. You only need to use native integer types if you plan on using the field as a primitive data element in your code.

Comment: What is with the stuf in the frame controll? Like "to ds"? It's 1 bit in size, so i have also to use char to_ds[1] or is there a way to make it smaller, because its just a flag? Something like an boolean, but with bits. And: The network data. Just char network_data[2312]?

Comment: Use `char[2]` for the entire frame control word(s), or `uint16_t` if you need to look inside it conveniently.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me a lot. Is there a 'flexible variable' for the network data? Or do i really have to reserve 2312 bytes, even if this one could be just 1000 bytes in size?